# Android multiple ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, drag, drawable, multi-touch

The MotionEvent class has ACTION_DOWN for the first and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN for any subsequent presses, same withh ACTION_UP. Evidently, there isn't an equivalent for ACTION_MOVE from what I've seen. I want to be able to move multiple drawables with the drag simultaneously. As is, it works fine for multiple presses (just invalidate() for and redraw at the current y location) but will only drag one drawable at a time. I tried making a for loop to go through every pointer, but no dice. Any suggestions?

```
    if(touchnX >= f.getLeft() &&
        touchnX <= f.getRight() &&
        touchnY <= f.getBottom() &&
        touchnY >=f.getTop()){
            f.moveThumb(touchnY);
            break;
    }
```

That's basically it for the code. I just need to know how to catch subsequent drags.

Comment: Each pointer gets its own position data.  This data isn't tied to what `drawables` are allowed to be moved on the screen.  You probably have some faulty code controlling this process somewhere.  There isn't enough posted above to tell.

Comment: I know each pointer gets its own data. My question is, how do I make implement the ACTION_MOVE case for more that one pointer simultaneously? Like for ANCTION_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the for loop through every pointer?  What worked for me is:

```
if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    int numPointers = event.getPointerCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numPointers; i++) {
        handleMoveEvent(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
    }
}
```

However, this will handle move events for all pointers, even if only one moved. I'm not quite sure how to get around that.